# C++ stdlib container class hierarchy

Tags: c++

I've been wondering, is there any reason for the design decision in C++ to not have a pure abstract class for any of the std library containers?

I appreciate that hash_map came later from the stdext namespace but shares a very similar interface. In the event that I later decide I would like to implement my own map for a particular piece of software, I would have preferred to have some kind of interface to work with.

*Example*

```
std::base_map *foo = new std::map<std::string, std::string>;
delete foo;
foo = new stdext::hash_map<std::string, std::string>;
```

Obviously the above example is not possible, as far as I am aware, however this is similar for list and other std lib containers.

I appreciate that this is not C# or Java, but there is obviously no constraints in C++ to stop this design, so why was it designed like this so that there is no coupling between similar containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because virtual functions add overhead.

Because the containers *don't* all have the same interface, there are common functions but also important differences regarding iterator invalidation and memory allocation (and so exception behaviour) which you need to understand, if you were using an abstract base you wouldn't know the specifics of how the concrete container would behave.

If you want to write code that is agnostic about the type of container it is passed then in C++ you write a template instead of relying on abstract interfaces, i.e. use *static polymorphism* not *dynamic polymorphism*.  That avoids the overhead of dynamic dispatch and also allows specialization based on concrete type, because the concrete type is known at compile time.

Finally, it wouldn't have any advantage IMHO. It's better the way it is. As you say, this isn't C# or Java, thankfully.

(P.S. the stdext namespace is not part of C++, it appears to be Microsoft's namespace for non-standard types, a better example would use `std::tr1::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of `stdext::hash_map`)

Comment: This clears it up, I had overlooked virtual function overhead and I understand what you say about using static polymorphism. I appreciate that all containers don't all have the same interface but I was under the impression that shared functionality had its own interface. You could always down cast back to the sub type but I also appreciate that down casting is something that should avoided unless absolutely necessary. Thanks for your answer! :-)

Comment: C++'s RTTI is very limited and you can't use reflection or anything to find the concrete type, so  you can't downcast unless you already know what the concrete type is, and if you already know why are you using polymorphism?